# Notation for "the" left adjoint functor

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, notation, adjoint-functors

As far as I know, there is no "official" notation for the left adjoint of a functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ if it exists. I have seen the notation $F^*$ sometimes, but this looks only nice when $F$ is already written as $F_*$, which is not practical. (This notation is then motivated by direct and inverse image functors. And it seems to be quite common for adjunctions between preorders aka Galois connections.) Similarly, I have seen the notation $F_*$ for the right adjoint of $F$, which only looks nice when $F$ is already written as $F^*$. I have also seen the notation $F^{\dagger}$ for the right adjoint, which looks nice, but then how would you denote the left adjoint if it exists? Perhaps ${}^{\dagger} F$? I don't want to start a debate here what is a good notation or not, since this is subjective anyway and is not suited for mathoverflow. I would like to know:

**Are there any textbooks, influential papers or monographs on category theory which have introduced a notation for the left adjoint of $F$? Is there any notation which has been used by multiple authors?**

Just to avoid any misunderstanding: Of course there is the official notation $F \dashv G$ when $F$ is left adjoint to $G$, but $\dashv$ is a relation symbol. I am interested in a function symbol (which makes sense since left and right adjoints are unique up to canonical isomorphism if they exist).

Comment: I've no idea how widely used it is, but I like $F^L$ for the left adjoint and $F^R$ for the right one.

Comment: @Adrien Thanks. Can you give an example of a book where it is used?

Comment: You could write it as a formula using limits: $d\mapsto \lim(\pi:d/F\to C)$.

Comment: I think the use of $F$ for a start is problematic. Often $F$ is the left adjoint as it is often used for 'free' with $U$ or similar standing for 'underlying'. Different contexts require different notation but I have used $L$ for the left adjoint and $R$ for the right when discussing adjoint functors when teaching category theory. It might help if you gave more idea of the context in which you are wanting this.

Comment: @TimPorter I completely agree. But sometimes the letters $U,L,R$ are already taken, or when no other functor is in the context, it is very common to name the functor $F$. By the way, Borceux calls $F$ the right and $G$ the left adjoint, yikes!

Comment: @Adrien, [how about](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351702/notation-for-the-left-adjoint-functor#comment881548_351702) ${^{\text L}F}$ and $F^{\text R}$?  (EDIT:  Ah, this is basically @‍FredRohrer's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/351714).)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In EGA 0.1.5.2-3 (from the 1971 Springer edition) the right adjoint and the left adjoint of a functor $F$ are denoted by $F^{\rm ad}$ and ${}^{\rm ad}\!F$, respectively.

Comment: I am very happy about this answer, and I accept it right away (even though there might be other books with other notations) because EGA I has/had such a huge impact. I didn't read all of the preliminaries, so I wasn't aware that this notation is introduced there. Well spotted!

Comment: Yet, this leads to the question why this notation is not common, even not in EGA itself (right?).

Comment: Let me also remark that the same section introduces a notation for the bijection $$\hom(F(x),y) \xrightarrow{\sim} \hom(x,F^{\text{ad}}(y)),$$ namely $f \mapsto f^{\flat}$, and $g \mapsto g^{\sharp}$ for the inverse. At least, this notation can be seen a lot in EGA.

Comment: I am quite sure that the "ad"-notation does not occur in EGA outside the cited section.

Comment: I've seen the notation $\lceil f \rceil$ and $\lfloor f \rfloor$ being used for the isomorphism, mainly in a few comp sci papers

Comment: @WorldSEnder I think I've used this notation myself, and it comes by analogy to the fact that floor and ceiling are adjoints to the inclusion of posets $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The floor is very nice and was always my prefered one. Yet (depending on the context of course) you may be willing to use the ad notation.

Comment: I always use the $\flat$ and $\sharp$ notation as well, but in the exactly opposite way. It seems to make more sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

P. Gabriel uses $F_\lambda$ for the left adjoint and $F_\rho$ for the right adjoint. See for instance p. 344 of the article "Covering spaces in representation theory" by K. Bongartz and P. Gabriel (Invent. Math. **65**, 1982) ([EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/142855)).